# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Google\Service\Exception: { "error": "unauthorized_client", "error_description": "Unauthorized" }

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-sheets-api

I followed all the steps mentioned in https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/php

but I'm getting following error:-

`PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Google\Service\Exception: { "error": "unauthorized_client", "error_description": "Unauthorized" } in /usr/local/var/www/web/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Http/REST.php:128`

Comment: Have you created the necessary credentials? https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/create-credentials#web

Comment: yup, also I'm able to read sheeet, in my golang project, but in PHP It throws an error

Comment: Hi there @ABHI KHANDELWAL! Could you please check on the [Cloud](https://console.cloud.google.com/home/dashboard) if your project has enabled the Sheets API? Did you just copy the script as it is written on the quickstart? If you made some modifications, please share them here.

Comment: Can you atleast add on which step are you getting the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other things aside, please make sure that you have chosen Web Browser and give the origin url is set correctly. For PHP, I suggest Web Browser option.

[image: Configure OAuth Client Img]

OR PERHAPS you have to generate the client Id and secret Id again and try.