# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google\Service\Exception' with message '{ "error": "unauthorized_client", "error_description": "Unauthorized" }

Tags: php, api, calendar, google-calendar-api

This is the code I have and it does not work for me, it returns the error commented on the subject. I have done the whole process by registering, delegating the entire domain and authorizing everything and it fails...

```
$REDIRECT_URI = 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$KEY_LOCATION = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/cada/includes/classes/google-api-php-client-2.1.1/client_secret_1050007893675-7bkmqjiqr1p57s9alr7fu7e016lrh5hc.apps.googleusercontent.com.json';
$TOKEN_FILE   = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/cada/share/token.txt";

$SCOPES = array(
    Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR
);

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("SimesatSat");
$client->setAuthConfig($KEY_LOCATION);



// Incremental authorization
$client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);

// Allow access to Google API when the user is not present. 
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setRedirectUri($REDIRECT_URI);
$client->setScopes($SCOPES);


if (isset($_GET['code']) && !empty($_GET['code'])) 
{
    try 
    {
        // Exchange the one-time authorization code for an access token
        $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($_GET['code']);
      
        // Save the access token and refresh token in local filesystem
        file_put_contents($TOKEN_FILE, json_encode($accessToken));
      
        $_SESSION['accessToken'] = $accessToken;
        header('Location: ' . filter_var($REDIRECT_URI, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
        exit();
    }
    catch (\Google_Service_Exception $e) 
    {
        print_r($e);
    }
}

if (!isset($_SESSION['accessToken'])) 
{
    $token = @file_get_contents($TOKEN_FILE);
  
    if ($token == null) 
    {
        // Generate a URL to request access from Google's OAuth 2.0 server:
        $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
      
        // Redirect the user to Google's OAuth server
        header('Location: ' . filter_var($authUrl, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
        exit();
    } 
    else 
    {
        $_SESSION['accessToken'] = json_decode($token, true);
    }
}

$client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['accessToken']);



/* Refresh token when expired */
if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) 
{
    // the new access token comes with a refresh token as well
    $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
    file_put_contents($TOKEN_FILE, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
}


////////////CONSULTA DATOS ////////////////////////////
$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

$results = $service->calendarList->listCalendarList();

print_r($results);
```

Can anybody help me? I have another project with another client with the same code and it works perfectly! I do not understand what's happening. The only difference is that this project is part of a subdomain. Could that be the mistake?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68701040/php-fatal-error-uncaught-google-service-exception-error-unauthorized-cli is this helpful?

Comment: thanks, but i have tried all stackoverflow comment options, and i keep getting the same response